# JS\Jquery можно ли создать свой ивент?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Имеется подгрузка скриптов(JQuery) на сайт, по завершению всех загрузок я бы хотел испустить сигнал, мол загрузка закончена и можно начинать работу. Сейчас нужные функции впихнуты в .done, но это не очень удобно.

Comment: @RubaXa оформите в ответ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
$.event.trigger('loaded', ["foo", "bar"]);

// использование
$(document).bind('loaded', function (evt, foo, bar){ alert(foo + bar); });
```

или

```
// создаем Deffered
$.ready = $.Deffered();

// Вызываем когда всё готово
$.ready.resolve();

// ожидаем готовности
$.ready.done(function (){ /*...*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

В библиотеках `Backbone` и `Matreshka` (скорее всего и в других, я просто не знаю больше) есть возможность создавать пользовательские события. Пример в `Backbone`:

```
var App = {};  
_.extend(App, Backbone.Events, {  
   App.on('element:loaded', function(){ /* do smth */ })  
})
```

запуск:

```
App.trigger('element:laoded');
```